# How to get the vertices coordinates of meshes for each step of the physics simulation?

Tags: python, physics, vertices, cloth-simulation, coordinates

I am running some physics simulations which involves a couple of mesh objects. I would like to get the vertices coordinates of one or two of the meshes in the scene while the physics simulation is running and store them into a file on disk, for each simulation step. The only way I can think of doing this is to somehow pause the physics simulation and get the vertices via `[mat * vert.co for vert in obj.data.vertices]` which seems to be complicated and maybe impossible (since pausing the simulation is not easy). So I wonder, is there an easier way to get the vertices coordinates?